# how to find a substring from a particular row of a file in python

Tags: python, file

I am trying to read a **.txt** file with hundreds of names and i want to look for a particular name.

For example, I have several names like

```
John simons
kumar ayush singh
peter calpidi
david brown
```

etc and I want to look for a substring **ayush** and if the substring exists I want to return complete string like `kumar ayush singh`.

I tried something like this:

```
try:
    with open('D:\\Any One\\name_list.txt') as names:
        for row in names:
            if row.find(request.strip()) != -1:
               results = row
               print(row)
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

but got an error :

```
'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 4467: character maps to undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REF: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#open

Review the errors options for the one you prefer. In the code, I put replace because it will put a marker where the error occurred and continue to process the file.

```
try:
    with open('D:\\Any One\\name_list.txt',errors='replace') as names:
        for row in names:
            if row.find(request.strip()) != -1:
               results = row
               print(request)
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

Comment: it's not showing errors now. but it's still not returning name as string for some reason?? any guess why??

Comment: could this be because of find method. i mean i don't use it often so it may be not useful here..??

Comment: Seems like you want  to print(request)

Comment: Please accept my answer if it solved the issue.